# Range comparison for alphanumeric

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, if-statement, model-view-controller

[image]There is a Branch DDL(list ATL1,ATL2) and 2 user input textboxes starteLetterGroupFrom and EndLetterGroupThru.

If the branch selected is 'ATL1' then the above 2 textboxes should have values only between of 000000 - JZZZZZ.
For 'ATL2' it should have values between K00000 - ZZZZZZ.

Ex:
if user tries to select ATL2 and enters AAAAAA-BZZZZZ in textboxes then it should not allow.
similarly,ATL1 cannot be assigned to SAAAAA-ZZZZZZ

```
    var branch = document.getElementById("selectBranch");
    var branchText = branch.options[branch.selectedIndex].text
    var startltr = $('#inputStartLetter').val().toUpperCase()
    var endltr = $('#inputEndLetter').val().toUpperCase();
```

Comment: What does this have to do with C#?

Comment: It is not clear at all what you are referring to when you say: **"If the branch is ATL1..."** or **"For ATL2 it should have..."**.  As a result of this, it is not clear what your question actually is.